# Refactoring a method which returns false if an some exception is thrown

Tags: java, exception, java-8, try-catch, refactoring

I have this method which should only return true when for all items in a list (`List<Foo> foos`) no exception occurs:

```
public boolean isHealthy(){
    try{
        for(final Foo myFoo : foos){
           checkConnection(myfoo);
        }
    }
    catch(DataAccessException | SQLException ex){
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

where `checkConnection` is a void method which can throw an exception

```
  void checkConnection(final Foo myFoo) throws SQLException{
      // ...
  }
```

I want to refactor `isHealthy` to make it some how readable because that return from a catch block looks not so elegant and even when the method has only 9 lines it is not obvious at first glance what it does with the nested try-for-catch block. Are there some java 8 features (Optionals, streams ..) which could help hier?

Comment: I might put `return true;` inside the `try`part, after the `for` loop. Then at least the reader knows that s/he has to look deeper for the return value. Anyway your method is already in line with my coding style.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd delegate a connection check wrapped in the `try-catch` for each `Foo` into a separate method returning `boolean` based on the connection result:

```
boolean isConnected(final Foo myFoo) {
    try {
        checkConnection(myFoo);
        return true;
    } catch(DataAccessException | SQLException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}

void checkConnection(final Foo myFoo) throws SQLException {
    // ...
}
```

The health check itselfs becomes fairly simple and readable using `Stream::allMatch` checking whether all connection checks are `true`.

```
public boolean isHealthy(){
    List<Foo> foos = ...
    return foos.stream().allMatch(this::isConnected);
}
```